# Javascript HTTP request authentication error

Tags: javascript, authentication

I am trying to call a webservice but I get a authentication error. It is a cross origin request. I have set the 'withcredentials' attribute to manage cross origin requests. But i am still getting the same error.

```
SOAPClient._loadWsdl = function(url, method, parameters, async, callback) 
 {

var wsdl = SOAPClient_cacheWsdl[url];
if (wsdl + "" != "" && wsdl + "" != "undefined")
    return SOAPClient._sendSoapRequest(url, method, parameters, async, callback, wsdl);
var xmlHttp = SOAPClient._getXmlHttp();
if (SOAPClient.username && SOAPClient.password) {
    xmlHttp.open("GET", url + "?wsdl", async, SOAPClient.username, SOAPClient.password);
    var auth = "Basic " + SOAPClient._toBase64(SOAPClient.username + ":" + SOAPClient.password);

    xmlHttp.withCredentials = true; 
    //xmlHttp.setRequestHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'www.website.com');
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', auth);
} else {
    xmlHttp.open("GET", url + "?wsdl", async);
}
if (async) {
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        alert(xmlHttp.readyState);
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
            SOAPClient._onLoadWsdl(url, method, parameters, async, callback, xmlHttp);
    }
}

xmlHttp.send(null); 
if (!async) `enter code here`
return SOAPClient._onLoadWsdl(url, method, parameters, async, callback, xmlHttp);
```

}

Comment: May you expand your current problem statement? "What am I doing wrong" is a bit vague. Please explain what it is you expect, what is actually happening, and provide any errors being thrown.

Comment: i am getting a 401 error when I make the request. I have set the withcredentials attributes but the error doesn't seem to go.

Comment: (can you edit the question?)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is due to limitations of the browser that won't allow you to do a CORS request. The header would have to be set on the remote server to permit this and it sounds like you don't control it.

Create a server proxy at the domain of the page that can fetch the desired result from the other domain and relay it to you from the allowed domain.

You may want to post the URL of the WDSL server to see if other people can consume it.

p.s.

```
 && wsdl + "" != "undefined")
```

This will never evaluate to undefined because you are always concatenating an empty string.